# Not sure how to demonstrate the base case in this problem of mathematical induction

Tags: number-theory, induction

I am trying to prove the formula for the sum of the terms in a finite geometric sequence by using the principle of mathematical induction.

**Theorem:** If $x$ is any real number other than 1, then:

$$ \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} x^j = \frac{x^n-1}{x-1}.$$

I know to start by demonstrating the base case, for which $n = 0. $

$$x^0 = \frac{x^0-1}{x-1}$$

However, if I try to simplify this, I do not see how both sides are equal to each other.

$$1 = \frac{0}{x-1}.$$

Is there someway to algebraically manipulate the base case that I am not seeing. Any help would be very useful. Thank you.

Note: I apologize for including my equations as links to images. I have copied them from Word, as I do not yet understand how to write equations in StackExchange.

Comment: better to make $n=1$ your base case

Comment: @311411 Why would the base case be n = 1 and not n = 0, since the sum of the sequence starts from 0?

Comment: because you'd have to assign some kind of meaning to $$\sum_{j=0}^{-1} A(j)$$

Comment: Unfortunately, the theorem specifies for which $x$ it shall apply, but not for which $n$ ... Incidentally, the only sensible meaning one can give to $\sum_{j=0}^{-1}$ is $0$ and indeed that interpretation makes the case $n=0$ of the theorem work, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beware: the summation goes from index $0$ to $n-1$, hence when $n=0$, it is the *empty* sum which evaluates as $0$.
Since $x\ne 1$, the division on the right hand side is valid and gives $\frac0{x-1}=0$.